# running tensorboard for the code in "Hands-On Tensorboard for Developers" by Joe Laba

Tags: python-3.x, tensorboard

I am attempting to run the code in Video 1.3 of this series on a Windows 10 machine. I am using the VScode IDE with Python 3.7 64 bit IDE from the Miniconda3 distribution. I have solved many config errors between versions of tensorflow, tensorboard, and Cuda and have generated a run file. Running tensorboard --logfile=./runfile from the directory now runs without and error but it does nothing. Does not output a URL and when I try to open localhost:6006 from my Firefox browser, it can't find it. I love puzzles but am now frustrated.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

#import numpy as np #Change all calls to numpy instead of np or set np = numpy
import os
import sys
import argparse

"""
This code implements the tensor board programming from 
the book "Hands-On TensorBoard for PyTorch Developers [Video]" by joe Laba
The book/videos use Tensorboard 2.0.2, Torch 1.3.1.
It requires the use of the Python 3.7 64 bit environment which comes from 
the Miniconda3 folder. This upgrades to the following packages;
numpy (1.17.2)
pillow (7.1.1)
python (3.7.1)
pytorch (1.2.0)
scipy(1.3.1)
tensorboard(2.1.1)
tensorflow(2.1.0)
tensorflow-gpu (2.1.0)
theano(1.0.1)
torchvision (0.4.0)

Which compiles with no errors
NVidia driver 441.22
cuDnn 7.6.5
Cuda 10.2.95

"""
###################################################################
# Variables                                                       #
# When launching project or scripts from Visual Studio,           #
# input_dir and output_dir are passed as arguments automatically. #
# Users could set them from the project setting page.             #
###################################################################

input_dir = None
output_dir = None
log_dir = None

#################################################################################
# PyTorch imports.                                                               #
#################################################################################
import tensorflow
import tensorboard
#from tensorflow.python.keras.callbaccks import Tensorboard
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter



def main():
    print("I am now in main")
    # Set up Tensorboard
    #Writer will output to ./runs/ directory by default
    writer = SummaryWriter()

    for x in range(5):
        y=100*x
        writer.add_scalar ('y',y,x)

    writer.close()
    print("done with writer")
    print("more done with writer")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--input_dir", type=str, 
                        default=None, 
                        help="Input directory where where training dataset and                  metadata are saved", 
                        required=False
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--output_dir", type=str, 
                        default=None, 
                        help="Input directory where where logs and models are saved", 
                        required=False
                        )

    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    input_dir = args.input_dir

    main() #This causes main to run
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching the source docs for VS2019 environments and PED-514
I removed multiple unused environments. 
then I did pip3 uninstall ... of multiple versions of tensorflow, tensorboard and numpy.
then I did pip install of compatible versions of tensorflow (2.1.0), tensorboard (2.1.1) and numpy (1.18.3). Now things look great.